# iOS - Main view resizes - additional UIViews do not

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

In my XCode project, I have a xib file and the main view resizes for the iPhone 5 (as do its subviews).

I have additional UIViews in this Xib (they're not set as subviews of the main view, though) and these ones don't resize even though I have set the auto sizing properties.

[image: UIView in Xib file]

Am I doing something wrong or is there a reason that these additional UIViews aren't resizing?

Thanks.

EDIT: I am adding these views as subviews to a parent view in my viewdidload method. Maybe I should do it in viewWILLload?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I've managed to figure it out! You have to set the frame of the UIViews in viewWillAppear to be whatever size you want and then the subviews will resize.

Luckily, in my case, all my tall narrow views that you can see in the screen grab above, are all going to be the height of the screen, so I can set it there and have the subviews position/resize accordingly.